# How to fix ''ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2" error when loading model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I'm trying to save and load my keras model. It trains, evaluates, and saves fine (using .h5 to save model) but when I try to load the model I get the following error: 
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2.
Am I loading the model incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated!

This is the code block from where I'm saving the model.

```
    def ml(self):
            model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
            self.addLayer(model,145,6)
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

            optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

            model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                              optimizer=optimizer,
                              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 
                                       'mean_squared_error'])

            model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train,epochs=130)


            lm = model.evaluate(self.x_test, self.y_test, batch_size=300)
            model.save('my_model.h5')


    def addLayer(self, model, numNodes, numLayers):
            for i in range(numLayers):
                model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(numNodes,activation=tf.nn.relu))
```

To load from a different script:

```
    import keras
    from keras.models import load_model
    from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
    from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

    with CustomObjectScope({'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()}):
            model = load_model(mlPath)
```

While attempting to load the model I get the following error:

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Answer (score 0):

you can try to save only the weights of your model, then re-create it using exactly the same code, and loading only the weights. 
so change

```
model.save
```

to

```
model.save_weights('my_model.h5')
```

Then when you want to load your model, first, you re-create your model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
self.addLayer(model,145,6)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

and finally load the weights:

```
model.load_weights('my_model.h5')
```

This worked for me. 
Also, you could add an Input layer, together with the explicit input_shape in your model.